# Images shown as text

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface

I have seen some questions where images are shown as text labels. The text label is not *actually* text but an image with only the text label. However, the actual image is not shown. For example, see this screensot of [a question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/34816/22822):

[image: Image shown as text]

> Battery Image 1 Battery Image 2 Battery Image 3

These are shown as lables only and the actual images are not being displayed.

Why does this happen? How can I see the actual image that was posted by the question author?

I am using Firefox 18.0 (Beta) on a Windows XP computer, if that matters.

I am not sure if this was asked already. I searched, but I was unable to find any answer.

*UPDATE:*

I also tried on IE 8 and Google Chrome as well. They show missing image icons.

Comment: Wow! Even the screenshot that I tried to upload here has the same issue!

Comment: Strange - I can see the pictures. Have you tried another browser?

Comment: @LiamW Oh really? So is it only for me? Now I tried on IE 8 and Google Chrome as well. They show missing image icons. Will update question.

Comment: Looks like it is only you, or a minority. I'm currently using the Android browser, but I remember seeing the images in chrome as well.

Comment: It seems like you are unable to reach `http://stack.imgur.com/` where most images on the SX network are hosted. The images work for me too.

Comment: @Flow: I guess so... I tried from Firefox for Android and it showed images. I think my computer's network is not connecting to `http://stack.imgur.com/` for some reason. :( But it will work at home! :)

Comment: Most likely a proxy/firewall issue with your "uplink". I can see the images fine as well.

Comment: @Izzy Yeah... But I was able to upload the image with no issues! I can say that the problem is specific to this network only, works otherwise...

Comment: That's in fact strange. Still, v-c for "too localized" :)

Comment: No need to close, I don't think. This is a real issue that will be experienced by anyone who is not able to connect to stack.imgur.com. Incidently, @Flow, you should add that as an answer so Suraj can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you are unable to reach `http://stack.imgur.com/` where most images on the SX network are hosted. The images work for me. Maybe your network admistrator has blocked `imgur.com` for some reason.

Comment: I tested this out by adding a filter on adblock. When I blocked stack.imgur.com, I was unable to see any picture. But, I also did *not* see the text labels. So maybe there is more to the problem than just the site being blocked.

Comment: Maybe, at least we agree that it's a local issue. :)